# Javascript onload function not executing [program has specific requirements]

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an assignment for college that **requires** an external file for scripts and an `onload` function **in the body** of the document. I've tried everything I can think of to make it work, without any success.

The `onclick` function works just as expected. I've tried the document in both Firefox and Google Chrome, and no errors appear in the console window to indicate a mistake on my part.

I've tried `onload="load()"` and `onload="load();"` as well as `onload="alert("I've been loaded!")"` and the alert never executes. I haven't been able to find any other solution for the requirements of the assignment, so I'm at a total loss.

**Please keep the requirements I mentioned in mind when answering, thank you.**

This is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Assignment 2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/assign2.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/assign2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Assignment 2: Javascript Quiz</h1>

        Choose theme: <a onclick="change(1)">Default</a> |
            <a onclick="change(2)">Candy</a>

        <div id="questionBox" class="default">
            <h2>Question 1</h2>
            <div id="question" onload="load()"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the .js file:

```
function change(i)
{
    var questionbox = document.getElementById("questionBox");
    if(i === 1)
    {
        questionbox.className = "default";
    }
    else if(i === 2)
    {
        questionbox.className = "candy";
    }
}

function load()
{
    alert("Function load() has been called.");
}
```

Comment: `<body onload="load()">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div's are not supported by onload.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

only body, frame, iframe, img, input type="image", link, script and style are supported.

Comment: Oh, duh. Thank you, I can't believe I forgot about that.

Comment: @Twisted Could you pick my answer as the answer ? ^^